# Setting up a small PA system

Tags: mixing, live

My band has a Yamaha PA system and a small Behringer mixer.
Both the PA amp and the mixer have mic sockets so which unit
should the mics be plugged into?
Any help would be most useful
Stuart Hillier

Answer (score 1):

If your PA system is similar to the likes of the Yamaha StagePas 500, then it offers a similar functionality to the Behringer Mixer.

As such, you may wish to bypass the mixer altogether and plug your microphones directly to the PA Mixer.

However, your Behringer mixer may offer some added functionality to your PA mixer (like better EQs or on-board effects). Also, using the Behringer mixer may give some extra flexibility as to where the mixer is placed.

I may be able to provide a more accurate answer if you spell the model of both your PA and Behringer mixer.